# Hide form action value in the URL in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am creating a web application in Java. I created some JSP pages each having some form fields. All are post method type so it hides all the form fields. In each page it will call servlet and forward to next JSP page(like a step by step process.)) Welcome page is `index.jsp`. In the last JSP page also I am having form field which is also post method type. When I press sumbit button, it will call servlet and should forwartd to home page(That is `index.jsp`).

Last page action value is `finish`. In my servlet, I am using `RequestDispatcher` and forwarding to `index.jsp`. The the URL will be

`http://localhost:8080/myproject/finish`. 
As it is the home page, I wanted to hide that action value. So instead of `RequestDispatcher` I used 
`response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");` And then URL becomes
`http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsp`.

This is not a big issue. But still I am asking is there anyway to hide this `index.jsp` in the URL? It should be like when we open the site for the first time(`http://localhost:8080/myproject/`).

Comment: Try with `response.sendRedirect("/");`

Comment: It goes to `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Thanks. I tried `response.sendRedirect("/myproject");`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer finally. Thanks to @Sayem Ahmed for his reply as comments.

I tried this only

```
response.sendRedirect("/myproject");
```

Comment: **Using your context path as hardcoded String is a bad idea!** You should use `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath())`. Your context path "/myproject" might change in the future!